# Fetch records in the same order WITHOUT using ORDER BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I am new to T-SQL. Can someone tell me how to fetch records from a sql table in the same order WITHOUT using the order by clause?

Comment: Why are you avoiding the use of an order by clause? You could sort them in your collection afterwards in Java or C# to avoid the use of order by.  In java there is the Apache BeanUtils to make it very easy to sort a collection of objects on a given property.

Comment: Why would you want to avoid "order by"?

Answer (score 15):

That can't be done.  You might get lucky sometimes but you can't depend on it.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using SQL Server (since you mention T-SQL), you may have some amount of luck by defining a clustered index on the table, which forces a storage ordering on the rows within the table.  However, if you do not specify an *order by* clause, adding or removing joins or *where* clause conditions may cause that order to change because the optimizer may choose not to use that clustered index.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a clustered index defined which controls the sequencing/order, you can use index hints within the select.